# MySQL CURDATE() - yesteday is last day of the month

Tags: mysql

I have some problem whith such `mysql_query`

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', CURDATE()-1)
```

why if yesteday is last day of the month

the `CURDATE()-1` result is like `2010-04-00`

why not `2010-03-31`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you mix date and number, date is treated as number.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 day));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function?